# Can we use Objective-C category to extend C++ class?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am wondering if we can use Objective-C category to extend C++ class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't : categories/class extension are mechanisms that rely on Objective-C runtime.
However, you could wrap your C++ code in an Objective-C++ class, and you could extend this one with categories (although I've never tried that)

Answer (score 1):

Objective-C and C++ implement classes quite differently, so no, you can't use Objective-C to add methods to a C++ class. However, Objective-C and C++ play very nicely together. You can call C++ methods from Objective-C code and vice versa, and you can even mix Objective-C source and C++ source in the same file; this is known as Objective-C++.

Other answers mention wrapping your C++ class in an Objective-C class. To do that, you'd create an Objective-C class that has an instance variable that points to an instance of the C++ class in question. You could then create methods for the Objective-C class that parallel the C++ interface, and have each of those methods simply call its partner method on the C++ object.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly.  But your Objective-C class can wrap a C++ class pretty easily (see [this article](http://philjordan.eu/article/mixing-objective-c-c++-and-objective-c++) for some techniques).